# D3 Converting a Stacked Area Graph from tsv to csv using Mike Bostock's example

Tags: javascript, csv, typescript, d3.js

Hi I am new to D3 and was wondering how I can convert Mike Bostock's stacked area graph from using a tsv file to a csv file.

Link to the graph: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211

When I try to use a csv file it tells me:
"Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,-16200LNaN,-…"."

at this line:
".attr("d", area);"

Much help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `d3.csv` to read the file instead of `d3.tsv`?

Comment: yeah its just with this example using the tsv has a different way of parsing the info out or something

Answer (score 0):

What does you .csv file look like?  D3 would expect a file like:

```
"date","Google Chrome", "Internet Explorer", "Firefox", "Safari", "Microsoft Edge", "Opera", "Mozilla", "Other/Unknown"
"2015 Jun 15",48.09,24.14,18.82,7.46,0.03,1.32,0.12,0.01
```

If your numeric values in the .csv are quoted, then you would also need to convert them to numeric type when you load the data file, like this:

```
d3.csv("filename.csv", function(err, data){
  if(err){
    //handle error
  }
  data.forEach( function(d){
    //convert to numberic
    d.Firefox = +d.Firefox
  }
})
```

Comment: https://shrib.com/#qoXUPP9so0h0CDS9bK9p

sorry I can't format it correctly here but heres a link to it

Comment: you'll need to post your code.  how did you define the area function?

Comment: the code is exactly the link to Mike Bostock's example. I am just modifying the tsv to csv part of the code.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mdml/8305340

I've also tried using use this example but with my csv file and It will not plot